# Get data from specific column using SPFx

Tags: spfx, 2019

I want to get list data from a specific column and use it to validate if data already exists then deny. The validation will be used in a SPFx form that I already have. There is no need to display the list data. Just use it for validation.

How can I achieve this?

This is for SharePoint Server 2019

Thanks,
Peter